# this.props.onFetchEventDetail is not a function in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

'onFetchEventDetail' function can't be called on componentDidMount.It shows this.props.onFetchEventDetail is not a function. I have made actions,reducers,selectors and saga for this function, all i need is this function to be triggered. Code is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {compose} from "redux";
import './EventDetailPage.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {requestEventDetail} from "./actions";
import {makeSelectEventDetail} from "./selectors";
import {createStructuredSelector} from "reselect";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import saga from "./saga";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import injectReducer from "utils/injectReducer";
import injectSaga from "utils/injectSaga";

export class EventDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("eventdetail:::" + this.props.match.params.eventId);
        this.props.onFetchEventDetail();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
        ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

EventDetail.propTypes = {
    eventId: PropTypes.string,
    onLoadFetchEventDetail: PropTypes.func,
};

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onFetchEventDetail: evt =>
            dispatch(requestEventDetail())
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    eventDetail: makeSelectEventDetail()
});

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
);

const withReducer = injectReducer({key: "eventDetailPage", reducer});
const withSaga = injectSaga({key: "eventDetailPage", saga});

export default compose(
    withReducer,
    withSaga,
    withConnect
)(EventDetail);
```

Comment: my i know how you are passing props to this component ?

Comment: Have you wired it up in mapDispatchToProps..please show the code for that

Comment: The code seems too incomplete to answer the question. Please update it to show a [mcve]

Comment: here requestEventDetail is the function from actions.js

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onFetchEventDetail: evt =>
            dispatch(requestEventDetail())
    }
}